# Annoying bug in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I'm doing a project and i needed to write two functions. The first is mk_key and its job is to convert a 24 RGB image into a vector consisting of consecutive bytes followed by a trailer consisting of 4 bytes that hold the dimensions of the image for reconstructing (so the vector size is [1 m*n*3+4]) then the elements of that vector are shuffled randomly according to a seed value (acting like a password) and finally the vector is saved to a file using hexa bytes; the other function is use_key and it is used to reconstruct the image from the key file, this is done by re-arranging the vector elements back into their positions and then using the data at the trailer to reconstruct the full RGB image. The only problem i have is that the reconstructed image has most of it's pixels lost and it only shows about 1/6 of the image and only at the red plane, the bytes at the other planes appear gray.

mk_key:

```
function mk_key(img, dest_file, seed)
s=size(img);
m=s(1);
n=s(2);
rg = zeros([1 m*n 3],'uint8');


 for i=drange(1:m)
    for j=drange(1:n)
    rg(1,n*i+j-n,:)=img(i,j,:); %convert rectangular image matrix into row image
    end
 end


rgf = zeros([1 (m*n*3)+4],'uint8');
for x=drange(1:3)
    rgf(1,(m*n*(x-1))+1:m*n*x)=rg(1,1:m*n,x);
end


mm=uint16(m);
nn=uint16(n);

rgf(1,(m*n*3)+1)=uint8(bitand(mm,hex2dec('00ff')));
rgf(1,(m*n*3)+2)=uint8(bitshift(bitand(mm,hex2dec('ff00')),-8));
rgf(1,(m*n*3)+3)=uint8(bitand(nn,hex2dec('00ff')));
rgf(1,(m*n*3)+4)=uint8(bitshift(bitand(nn,hex2dec('ff00')),-8));

rng(seed); 
idxs = randperm(((m*n*3)+4)); % generate a random sequence representing byte locations

sg = zeros([1 ((m*n*3)+4)],'uint8');
for i=drange(1:((m*n*3)+4))
sg(1,i)=rgf(1,idxs(i));
end


f = fopen(dest_file, 'w'); 
for i=drange(1:((m*n*3)+4))
    fprintf(f, '%x %x', sg(1,i));
end
fclose('all');
end
```

use_key:

```
function [img]=use_key(source_file, seed)
key_file=fopen(source_file);
key=fscanf(key_file,'%x %x');
key=key'; %Transpose column vector into row vector
key=uint8(key);
s=size(key);
rng(seed); 
idxs = randperm(s(2)); % generate a random sequence representing byte locations
mgf = zeros([1 s(2)],'uint8');
for i=drange(1:s(2))
    mgf(1,idxs(i))=key(1,i);
end

m=uint16(mgf(1,s(2)-3))+uint16(mgf(1,s(2)-2))*(16^2);
n=uint16(mgf(1,s(2)-1))+uint16(mgf(1,s(2)))*(16^2);

img = zeros([m n 3],'uint8');    

for x=drange(1:3)
   for i=drange(1:m)
       for j=drange(1:n)
       img(i,j,x)=mgf(1,(n*i+j-n)+(m*n)*(x-1));%convert row matrix into rectangular image matrix
       end
   end
end

fclose('all');
end
```

Comment: That's a terrible title.  If you had a list of MATLAB question titles (only, without authors), could you even find your question in the list?

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, it is a terrible title. I couldn't find a more suitable title for this mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the bug is, it's *somewhere* in those horrible nested loops. Rather than attempt to fix what looks like a direct port of C code, I started cleaning up all the confusing and needlessly overcomplicated bits so I could make sense of it; by the time I'd finished, there wasn't much left:

```
function mk_key(img, dest_file, seed)
s = uint16(size(img));
s = typecast(s(1:2), 'uint8');
rg = reshape(img, 1, []);
rgf = [rg s];

rng(seed);
idxs = randperm(numel(rgf));
sg = rgf(idxs);

f = fopen(dest_file, 'w');
fprintf(f, '%x ', sg);
fclose(f);
end
```

and correspondingly:

```
function [img] = use_key(source_file, seed)
key_file = fopen(source_file);
key = fscanf(key_file,'%x');
fclose(key_file);

rng(seed);
idxs = randperm(numel(key));
mgf = zeros(1, numel(key), 'uint8');
mgf(idxs) = key;

s = typecast(mgf(end-3:end), 'uint16');
img = reshape(mgf(1:end-4), s(1), s(2), 3);
end
```

Whilst the ordering from `reshape` is different compared to your loops, that makes no practical difference given that the vector then gets shuffled - it's more robust,  works as expected and is considerably quicker.

Comment: You are a life saver. I tried your version and it ran like magic.

Comment: Also, the way i wrote the code in c-like statements is because i haven't had much experience working on higher level languages. And that makes my code run like death.

Comment: @AhmedIhsanTawfeek Don't worry - learning to "think in Matlab" is quite a jump from most other languages where you don't have things like indexing and vectorised functions. My advice is to spend plenty of time with the documentation, and _always_ start with the thought "does Matlab already have a way to do this?"